# How to include numeric characters like time in regex pattern while reading data from csv file?

Tags: regex

I am reading data from csv file, where Iam able to read the data even data has comma(,) in it using regex below, but unable to include time in that pattern ? can someone suggest how to match that.

```
Regex : (".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)
```

I need to include 2:00:00 AM as well

[image]

Comment: You should instead use a proper CSV _parser_ which can handle all edge cases.

Comment: I am using this regex in my java script code, where it is treating time as separate word and AM as separate word, so if we modify regex that may work, I tried a lot but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following regex match all approach in JavaScript:

```js
var input = '"23,42",ewtwe, sf,asf,2:00:00 AM,3;8;,3;8;';
var items = input.match(/".*?"|[^,\s]+(?:\s+[^,\s]+)*/g);
console.log(items);
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `".*?"` a doubly quoted term
- `|` OR
- `[^,\s]+` a non whitespace term excluding commas
- `(?:\s+[^,\s]+)*` optionally followed by whitespace and more similar terms

Note that we search eagerly first for doubly quoted terms, and only that failing do we use comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

We can add this part `(?: \w+)?` after `[^",\s]+`.

`[^",\s]+` match one or more character except `"`, `,` and `\s`.

`(?: \w+)?` followed by an optional (space   and `\w+` one or more word character). the `(?:` is the opening of the non-capturing group and the last `)` is the closing bracket of it. The `?` after the closing bracket makes the whole group optional.

```
(".*?"|[^",\s]+(?: \w+)?)(?=\s*,|\s*$)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsOlUA/1)